How well does taking the $n$ out of $N$ samples farthest from the mean approximate a normal distribution?
Sample $N$ times from a normal distribution. Take $n<N$ of the "worst" samples (i.e., the samples that are the furthest from the mean and maximize $|x-\mu|$). I presume the best way to approximate the mean would simply be to take the mean of all of those values as we expect them to be evenly distributed across the tails. Is this going to be as accurate of an approximation as taking $n$ "best" samples (i.e., those that minimize $|x-\mu|$) or $n$ random samples?
Intuitively I think the average mean obtained from this process will be independent of taking the best, worst or random sampling method. However, if we for example take $n=7$ for the best samples we might expect a similar approximation as $n=6$ or $8$, but if we take $7$ of the worst approximations we can't expect one of them to be close to the mean so we might expect it to significantly shift the approximate mean to one side.
Hence, I might expect that the average mean will be the same for all of those sampling methods but the standard deviation of this approximation to be the highest for the "worst samples" method? Is there any way to quantify this? Does $n$ being odd or even affect the approximation enough that for example $n=6$ might have lower variance than $n=7$?

Yikes!  Avoid this estimator!
This is a terrible estimation method, especially because you are not even forcing it to take an equal number of points from the two tails.  Because you are taking the extreme values in the tails, and because you are not even forcing equal sampling from the two tails, there is a high probability that you will get an imbalanced sample from each tail and so the estimated mean will be heavily weighted in the direction of the tail which includes the most sample points.  This will massively increase the variance of your estimator as it swings wildly from one extreme to the other in different samples.  Each of the three methods you specify here give an unbiased estimator, but the variance on the method taking the extreme samples will be huge, particularly if $n$ is relatively small.
In the R code below I will simulate the performance of your three estimators (which I call the FullMean, CloseMean and FarMean) for the case where $N=100$ and $n=10$, representing a fairly modest subsample of extreme values from the initial sample.  In order to give a broader comparison, I have also included two additional estimators (which I call CloseMeanEven and FarMeanEven) that use either the points closest or furthest from the sample mean, but counting an equal number of points from each tail.  (Note that the estimator CloseMeanEven is just the trimmed mean of the sample.)
#Set parameters
SIMS <- 10^5
N    <- 100
n    <- 10

#Simulate standard normal samples
set.seed(521423837)
X <- matrix(rnorm(SIMS*N), nrow = SIMS, ncol = N)

#Identify tail points (allowing uneven tails)
T1 <- matrix(FALSE, nrow = SIMS, ncol = N)
for (s in 1:SIMS) {
  xx     <- abs(X[s,] - mean(X[s,]))
  T1[s,] <- (xx >= sort(xx, decreasing = TRUE)[n]) }

#Identify tail points (forcing even tails)
#This step assumes that n is even
T2 <- matrix(FALSE, nrow = SIMS, ncol = N)
for (s in 1:SIMS) {
  xx     <- X[s,] - mean(X[s,])
  T2[s,(xx >= sort(xx, decreasing = TRUE)[n/2])]  <- TRUE
  T2[s,(xx <= sort(xx, decreasing = FALSE)[n/2])] <- TRUE }

#Compute estimates for each simulation
EST.NAMES <- c('FullMean', 'CloseMean', 'FarMean', 'CloseMeanEven', 'FarMeanEven')
EST <- matrix(0, nrow = SIMS, ncol = 5)
rownames(EST) <- sprintf('Sim[%s]', 1:SIMS)
colnames(EST) <- EST.NAMES
for (s in 1:SIMS) {
  xx <- X[s,]
  t1 <- T1[s,]
  t2 <- T2[s,]
  EST[s, 1] <- mean(xx)
  EST[s, 2] <- sum(xx*(1-t1))/(N-n)
  EST[s, 3] <- sum(xx*t1)/n
  EST[s, 4] <- sum(xx*(1-t2))/(N-n)
  EST[s, 5] <- sum(xx*t2)/n }

From these simulated estimates we can estimate the mean and variance of the estimators (noting that the true mean here is zero).  This yields the following results, which confirms that the FarMean estimator is an absolutely terrible estimator.  In fact, this estimator is so bad that it has a variance roughly equivalent to what you would get if you took the full sample mean from only four data points.  We also see that the estimator is substantially improved (but still not great) if we use FarMeanEven which takes the average of the extreme points but forcing an even number of points to be used in each tail.
#Estimate variance of the estimators
MOM <- matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 5)
rownames(MOM) <- c('Mean', 'Var')
colnames(MOM) <- EST.NAMES
MOM[1, ] <- c(mean(EST[,1]), mean(EST[,2]), mean(EST[,3]), mean(EST[,4]), mean(EST[,5]))
MOM[2, ] <- c( var(EST[,1]),  var(EST[,2]),  var(EST[,3]),  var(EST[,4]),  var(EST[,5]))
MOM

         FullMean    CloseMean       FarMean CloseMeanEven  FarMeanEven
Mean 0.0001060659 0.0001588386 -0.0003688879  0.0001064976 0.0001021814
Var  0.0100123165 0.0130930288  0.2596676039  0.0102579432 0.0304252045


That's quite interesting, I expected it to be bad but not quite this bad. Also thanks for the code, I should be able to adapt it to check how changing $N$ and $n$ affect the mean and variance to answer the last part myself once I get a chance to run it.

I'll refer to the $n$ values of $x$ that are furthest from the mean as $y$. If $y$ is all you have to work with, simulation suggests a better estimate is
$$\frac{\left<y_{y<\bar{y}}\right>+\left<y_{y>\bar{y}}\right>}{2}$$
Where $\left<y_{y<\hat{y}}\right>$ refers to the mean of the $y$ values that are less than the mean of $y$.
This statistic is less sensitive to possible imbalances in the proportion of samples that are to the left of the mean vs. to the right.
Demonstrating with a simulation in R:
reps <- 1e6
N <- 100
n <- 10
Nn1 <- N - n + 1

sim <- replicate(
  reps, {
    # generate N random standard normal variates, sorted by distance from 0
    x <- sort(abs(rnorm(N)))*sign(runif(N, -1, 1))
    x1 <- x[Nn1:N]*sign(runif(n, -1, 1)) # n furthest samples
    c(
      mean(x),
      mean(sample(x, 10)),
      mean(x[1:n]*sign(runif(n, -1, 1))), # mean of n closest samples
      x0 <- mean(x1),
      (mean(x1[x1 < x0]) + mean(x1[x1 > x0]))/2
    )
  }
)

matrix(c(rowMeans(sim), apply(sim, 1, var)), 5, 2, 0,
       list(c("N-Mean", "n-Mean", "CloseMean", "FarMean", "FarMean2"),
            c("Mean", "Var")))
#>                    Mean          Var
#> N-Mean     8.822295e-05 0.0099776386
#> n-Mean     4.515257e-04 0.0998661729
#> CloseMean  9.430139e-06 0.0006731712
#> FarMean   -1.017196e-04 0.4331035138
#> FarMean2  -1.649571e-05 0.0355512557

The proposed alternative statistic ("FarMean2") is still inferior to using all $N$ samples, but it is a much better estimate than naively taking the mean of $y$. Somewhat surprisingly, it is also a better estimate than $n$ random samples of $x$ when $N = 100$ and $n=10$.

Interesting analysis (+1).  Not really that surprising that FarMean2 is better than n-Mean.  The former estimator has the advantage that it identifies its points as being evenly balanced in the two tails from a sample mean computed from a much bigger sample, so it is less likely to give subsamples that are weighted heavily to one end of the distribution.  In doing so, it is sneaking in the full sample through the back door (i.e., it is actually an estimator that uses $N$ data points, not $n$ data points).
